# How to find model values in HandleErrorAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I try to find model in error exception.
I have a HandleErrorAttribute class and I'm logging some of exception such as type,message,stacktrace. But i didnt find my model.
For example i need return A class from action but i returned B class. So it gave an error exception such as 'View need A class but you return B class'. In this time i need to learn what's the B class properties and values

(It's just example. Maybe it can be db exception or other types of exception)

My handle class :

```
 public class ErrorHandler : HandleErrorAttribute
 {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            MvcApplication.logger.Error(ex, "Exception Type => " + ex.GetType());
            MvcApplication.logger.Error(ex, "Exception Message => " + ex.Message);
            MvcApplication.logger.Trace(ex, ex.StackTrace);

            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                AllInnerExceptions(ex.InnerException);

        }

        private void AllInnerExceptions(Exception ex)
        {
            MvcApplication.logger.Error(ex, "   InnerException Type => " + ex.GetType());
            MvcApplication.logger.Error(ex, "   InnerException Message => " + ex.Message);
            MvcApplication.logger.Trace(ex, ex.StackTrace);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                AllInnerExceptions(ex.InnerException);
        }
}
```

Comment: `object model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model` should get it.

Comment: İt's work . Thank you :)